# Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer performance is choppy on device but not in Simulator

Tags: ios, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

Using the Ti.Media.VideoPlayer object.  Playing a simple, short .mp4 file, file size is 10.8MB, aspect is not being adjusted or modified, playing at 768x1024 (landscape orientation).
Building on SDK 2.1.4GA against iOS 5 for AdHoc Distribution.

Code itself is below:

```
    var videoPlayer = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
        top: 0,
        autoplay: true,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        height: 768,
        width: 1024,
        mediaControlStyle: Ti.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_NONE,
        repeatMode: Ti.Media.VIDEO_REPEAT_MODE_ONE
    });
    videoPlayer.url = '/app/assets/myVideo.mp4';
```

Anyone else had similar issues?

Comment: Which Devices did you test? Please describe what you mean with 'choppy'? Is frame rate lower than usual?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue, and it has nothing to do with the code, the module, or the implementation.  It was actually the video itself.  So anyone who runs across this, a video frame rate of 30fps will not work as far as I know.  Backing it off to 29.97fps worked perfectly, and exactly with the type of performance and playback expected.

Answer (score 0):

add following parameter while creating your VideoPlayer -

```
scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT
```